# Web Application IPC/RPC with Client Applications

Tags: windows, linux, web-applications, ipc, client-applications

#### Background

I'm at the planning stages of a DIY project that'll help me automate some hardware at my house. It's probably also worthwhile to mention that I've got almost no experience with web-related development.

---

#### The Basics

http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/4706/drawingo.png -- I can't seem to embed the diagram.

- In order to simplify management, I want to implement my UI in the browser.
- The meat of my application will reside inside a Windows service or Linux daemon; this does not mean, however, that I'm after a cross-platform solution -- I'm not tied to any particular platform, so I'll pick one (probably based on the responses that I get) and stick with it.
- I would *prefer* to use "free" tools (e.g., LAMP/WAMP), but it's not a deal breaker.
- It would be nice to be able to communicate back to the user that some action is in progress (I think AJAX would be one way to go?)

---

#### Questions

The only thing that's not entirely clear to me is the implementation of step № 3. I'd like to hear possible implementation ideas (on Windows or Linux) as to how this *should* be done. Hopefully some of you can share how this sort of thing is done in the real world.

---

#### Miscellaneous

As always, if there's a problem with my thinking, please point it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many people better qualified to help with step 3 so I'll leave that to them.

My question is whether is you are looking forward to learning the mess of web technologies required for the front end or consider it a necessary evil on the way to what you really want to accomplish?  If the latter (and assuming you are working in C/C++) consider taking a look at [WT](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt#/).  It's a toolkit that makes the developing the web interface seem more like a desktop gui while handling much of the ugliness for you.  It could potentially cut a lot of time off your development.

Comment: That's pretty damn sweet. Thanks! As for the "learning new technologies" part: I'm open to learn anything new. =)